# 404 on page refresh in NextJS with p5.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, p5.js

I'm using the `react-p5` library for generating PerlinNoise wave animation in my `about` page.
When I use the `p5` on any page it returns a 404 page, but if click back to the home page and open `about.js` using the link it will work. After refresh, it won't work.

Everything works if I remove the `p5` component from the file. I think the problem is with the `p5` or `p5 import`.

**about.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
// Importing Sketch
import Sketch from 'react-p5'


export default function about() {

// Setup for creating canvas
    const setup = (p5, canvasParentRef) => {
        p5.createCanvas(p5.windowWidth, 100).parent(canvasParentRef)
    }
    let inc = 0.005;
    let start = 0;

// Function to draw the wave
    const draw = p5 => {
        p5.background('rgba(255,255,255)')
        p5.stroke('rgb(0,0,0)');
        p5.noFill();
        p5.beginShape();
        let xoff = start;
        for (let x = 0; x < p5.width; x++) {
            p5.stroke('#000');
            let y = p5.noise(xoff) * p5.height;
            p5.vertex(x, y);
            xoff += inc;
        }
        p5.endShape();
        start += inc;
    }

    return (
        <>
// Returning Sketch Component
            <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} />
        </>
    )
}
```

Project Structure :

[image: Here]

Comment: can you create minimal reproduction on codesandbox?

Comment: Here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-river-yy8rwg?file=/pages/about.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Sketch component is wanting to access `window` property, but window is undefined since we serve server side rendered About page.

How to get around this?

Best solution would be to create a separated component, we can call it **DrawSketch**

DrawSketch component is almost identical to your About page with exception that it is a component.

```
import React from "react";
import Sketch from "react-p5";

export default function DrawSketch() {
  const setup = (p5, canvasParentRef) => {
    p5.createCanvas(p5.windowWidth, 100).parent(canvasParentRef);
  };
  let inc = 0.005;
  let start = 0;

  // Function to draw the wave
  const draw = (p5) => {
    p5.background("rgba(255,255,255)");
    p5.stroke("rgb(0,0,0)");
    p5.noFill();
    p5.beginShape();
    let xoff = start;
    for (let x = 0; x < p5.width; x++) {
      p5.stroke("#000");
      let y = p5.noise(xoff) * p5.height;
      p5.vertex(x, y);
      xoff += inc;
    }
    p5.endShape();
    start += inc;
  };

  return <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} />;
}
```

Next thing we want is to make sure that we will client side server our DrawSketch component, so it can has access to `window` property.

In next.js you can use dynamic imports

> Next.js supports ES2020 dynamic import() for JavaScript. With it you can import JavaScript modules dynamically and work with them. They also work with SSR.

Next step would be importing DrawSketch component we created inside your About view and declare it as dynamic component which is `not server side rendered`.

```
import React from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const ClientSideSketch = dynamic(() => import("../components/DrawSketch"), {
  ssr: false
});

export default function AboutPage() {

  return (
    <>
      <ClientSideSketch />
    </>
  );
}
```

I have edited [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-euler-9wd50o?file=/pages/about.js), so you can see working live example.